# Significant digits

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcSId}{o m m}
                                     {\SI[#1]{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}{#3}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcSIdcfr}{m m m}
        {\SI[round-mode = figures, round-precision = #1, round-integer-to-decimal]{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}{#3}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myformat}{m m}
                                {\fp_to_decimal:n{round((#1), #2)}}
%
\fp_set:Nn \mamol {30.07}
\fp_set:Nn \massetano {52.02}
\fp_set:Nn \nmoli {\massetano / \mamol}
%
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\begin{document}

\[ n = \calcSId{\nmoli}{\mole} \]

\[ n = \calcSId[round-mode = figures, round-precision = 4, round-integer-to-decimal]{\nmoli}{\mole} \]

\[ n = \calcSId{\myformat{\nmoli}{4}}{\mole}  \]

\[ n =  \calcSIdcfr{4}{\nmoli}{\mole} \]

\end{document}
```

I would like to have only one command like `\calcSId` that, without the optional parameter, will print the full calculated number. The same command, specifying the number of figures, should then print the number like `\calcSIdcfr`.

I don't know how to "insert" the `[round-mode = figures, round-precision = #1, round-integer-to-decimal]` (or other options) in automatic without to print it every time or to have a separate command like `\calcSIdcfr`.

Any suggestion or it is impossible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can condition on the existence of a value within the optional argument `#1` using `\IfValueTF{#1}{<true>}{<false>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcSId}{o m m}
  {\IfValueTF{#1}
     {\SI[round-mode = figures, round-precision = #1, round-integer-to-decimal]{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}{#3}}
     {\SI{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}{#3}}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcSIdcfr}{m m m}
  {\SI[round-mode = figures, round-precision = #1, round-integer-to-decimal]{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}{#3}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myformat}{m m}
  {\fp_to_decimal:n{round((#1), #2)}}

\fp_set:Nn \mamol {30.07}
\fp_set:Nn \massetano {52.02}
\fp_set:Nn \nmoli {\massetano / \mamol}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[ n = \calcSId{\nmoli}{\mole} \]

\[ n = \calcSId[4]{\nmoli}{\mole} \]

\[ n = \calcSId{\myformat{\nmoli}{4}}{\mole}  \]

\[ n = \calcSIdcfr{4}{\nmoli}{\mole} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, `\calcSId[4]{\massetano/\mamol}` will print the value without needing to compute it beforehand.

Comment: Yes, thank you. However in the actual calculation \nmoli is an intermediate value to be used elsewhere.